# Arizona TimeZone Day Light Saving

Tags: java, timezone, dst

I am trying to get current time in specific time zones. I tried following code.

```
Calendar j = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Mountain"));
j.setTimeInMillis(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println(j.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+j.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Mountain");
System.out.println("tz.getRawOffset()"+tz.getRawOffset()/3600);
System.out.println(tz.getDSTSavings());
System.out.println

(tz.inDaylightTime(new Date()));
```

The answer I got is surprising -
16:57 - wrong by 1 hr
tz.getRawOffset()-7000
3600000
true - why daylight saving is true for Arizona?
How to get the correct wall clock time of Phoenix or any other city in US?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arizona is [in the Mountain timezone, but doesn't observe DST](http://www.timetemperature.com/tzus/arizona_time_zone.shtml). If you specify the timezone "US/Mountain", then the computer will apply the rules used by most states in the Mountain time zone, which include observing daylight savings time. To get the rules for Arizona (which don't include DST), you want the timezone "US/Arizona" (or "America/Phoenix"). In the Navajo nation, you want the timezone named "Navajo".

To save yourself some of the trouble, always try to use the names from "America/*" where you can pick the name of a city that has the same timezone rules as the place you're interested in.

To get the correct time in the correct timezone for any given city in the world, you simply have to familiarize yourself with the names in the Olson timezone database and their meanings. While you usually think of the term "time zone" to mean the time of day in the middle of the winter (when everybody observes standard time), in the Olson database a timezone name represents the entire history of daylight savings time rules and timezone rules for a particular region.

As an example, even though [Indiana now observes Eastern time and observes DST](http://www.timetemperature.com/tzus/indiana_time_zone.shtml) (except for a few counties right near Chicago which are on Central time like Chicago), before 2006 they didn't observe DST. A timezone named "US/Indiana" (or "America/Indianapolis") was created to cover this region, an even today, you would still want to use the timezone "America/Indianapolis" when talking about Indiana, so that queries about dates and times before 2006 could be answered correctly.

Comment: The situation in Indiana is even more complex than outlined above.  Some counties used Eastern time and DST; some used Central time and DST; and most used Eastern time but did not observe DST.  The list of time zone names for Indiana in the Olson database includes all of these: America/Fort_Wayne,
America/Indiana/Indianapolis,
America/Indiana/Knox,
America/Indiana/Marengo,
America/Indiana/Petersburg,
America/Indiana/Tell_City,
America/Indiana/Vevay,
America/Indiana/Vincennes,
America/Indiana/Winamac,
America/Indianapolis,
America/Knox_IN,
US/East-Indiana,
US/Indiana-Starke.

Comment: @Jonathan: You're right. There were counties that have always observed daylight savings time in the Eastern time zone. Then when Indiana decided to adopt Daylight Savings time as a whole, a number of different counties on the border between the two timezones have switched back and forth between the two timezones at various times, so there really are [a whole lot more timezones for Indiana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Indiana). But as far as understanding how Olson designed his database, my simplified explanation of Indiana is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Most of Arizona does not observe Daylight Savings Time, but the Navajo Nation inside Arizona *does* observe DST.

Answer (score 2):

I am providing the modern answer. Don’t use the classes `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, `TimeZone` and `Date`. They are all poorly designed and fortunately all long outdated.

### java.time

It’s simple when you know how:

```
    ZonedDateTime arizonaExceptNavajo = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Phoenix"));
    System.out.println(arizonaExceptNavajo);
```

When I ran this code just now, the output was:

> 2019-10-23T04:07:23.034-07:00[America/Phoenix]

The US/Mountain time zone ID is deprecated. It’s a link to America/Denver, and America/Denver does use summer time (daylight saving time, DST). Modern time zone IDs have the form *region/city* where *region* is either a continent like America or an ocean like Pacific.

As others have said, summer time is used on one place in Arizona, the Navajo Nation. The `Navajo` time zone ID mentioned is deprecated too. Use America/Denver:

```
    ZonedDateTime navajoNation = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Denver"));
    System.out.println(navajoNation);
```

> 2019-10-23T05:07:23.037-06:00[America/Denver]

Since summer time is still in effect, the time of day is one hour ahead compared to the one for Phoenix above.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Navajo Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navajo_Nation) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

The zone information can be obtained directly for many major cities worldwide.  This includes Phoenix, which has the zone identifier "America/Phoenix".

You can find the list of available zone identifiers using the method *TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()* or by manually inspecting the contents of the JRE *lib/zi* directory.

As other posters have noted, the "US/Arizona" zone information is distinct from "US/Mountain".

Answer (score 0):

```
    Date timeTest = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
     
    SimpleDateFormat localFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa");
    String localTime = localFormater.format(timeTest);
    System.out.println("Local time :  " + localTime);
     
    SimpleDateFormat arFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa");
    arFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Arizona"));
    System.out.println("Arizona equivalent time :  " + arFormatter.format(timeTest));
     
    SimpleDateFormat mstFormmater = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa");
    mstFormmater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Mountain"));
    System.out.println("MST equivalent time   :  " +  mstFormmater.format(timeTest));
```

Output :

Local time :  08:43 AM 
Arizona equivalent time :  01:43 AM 
MST equivalent time   :  02:43 AM

But if we change the Calendar without changing the Dateformat , the output will be same for the Timezone-Format(MST, US/Arizona , US/Mountain ).

```
    Calendar userCalendar1 = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST"));<br>
    Calendar userCalendar2 = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Arizona"));<br>
    Calendar userCalendar3 = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Mountain"));
     
    Date timeTest1 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    Date timeTest2 = userCalendar1.getTime();
    Date timeTest3 = userCalendar2.getTime();
    Date timeTest4 = userCalendar3.getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat localFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa");
    String   localTime = localFormater.format(timeTest1);
    System.out.println(" Local   time 1:  " + localTime);
 
    localFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa");
    localTime = localFormater.format(timeTest2);
 
    System.out.println("Local   time  2:  " + localTime);
 
    localFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa");
    localTime = localFormater.format(timeTest3);

    System.out.println("Local   time 3:  " + localTime);

    localFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa");
    localTime = localFormater.format(timeTest4);
 
    System.out.println("Local   time 4:  " + localTime);
```

Output : 
Local   time 1:  08:56 AM 
Local   time  2:  08:56 AM
Local   time 3:  08:56 AM
Local   time 4:  08:56 AM

Comment: First of all the classes `Calendar`, `TimeZone` and `Date` were poorly designed, and `SimpleDateFormat` is a notorious troublemaker of a class. For this reason they were supplanted about a decade ago by java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Don't use those old classes. Second time zone IDs US/Arizona and US/Mountain are deprecated and replaced by America/Phoenix and America/Denver. Third, are you contributing anything not already in the other answers?

Comment: And nitpicking, I believe that the 9:52 in the first line of your output is not in EST but in EDT. Similarly the last line in MDT, not MST. And worse, naming your `Date` variable `estTime` is misleading since a `Date` hasn't got any time zone.